# draw tokens in the circle with jointjs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I want to draw some tokens (small circle) in the circle via jointjs, how can I do it ?

This code draw a circle with the text "token" and I want to replace "token" by a circle.

```
var place = 
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
    id:'place1',
    position: {x:100, y: 180},
    attrs: {circle: {fill: '#FFFFFF'}, text: {text:'TOKEN', fill:'#000000'}} 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for the JointJS Petri Net shapes plugin (joint.shapes.pn.js). See a demo at: http://jointjs.com/demos/pn. You can download the plugin from here: http://jointjs.com/download. Then use:

```
var place = new joint.shapes.pn.Place({
    position: { x: 140, y: 50 },
    tokens: 1
});
```

Comment: GREAT - Thanks very much - Yes, I want to draw a petri net. When I user your code, token is drawing but isn't full fill black (just a circle) ??? And how can I have the code of the petri net demo ?

Comment: It's ok now for drawing token, just because of my background color.

Comment: @NhuPhung, you can get the code of the Petri net demo here: http://jointjs.com/js/pn.js